# QML - Access QList data through model

Tags: qml

I was having an issue in trying to access C++ list data that is assigned to QML Repeater model.

Can this data be accessed without the help of a delegate?

For example:
C++:

```
QList<MyOwnStruct>  GetListData() // Invokable from qml
{
   QList<MyOwnStruct> infoData
   .... // Appended data 
   return infoData
}
```

QML:

```
Row {
    Repeater {
        model: GetListData()
        ....
    }
}
```

In the above example, I was able to get the exact count of infoData which repeater repeats. But I could not get more information from infoData like each individual element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accesses elements of your struct, you will need to convert your MyOwnStruct to something that QML can understand, example [QVariantMap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html).

So you could do something like this.

```
QVariantMap MyClass::GetData(int index) // Invokable
{
   QVariantMap var;

   MyOwnStruct infoData = infoListData[index];

   // Appended data 
    var.insert("elem_a", infoData.element_a);
    var.insert("elem_b", infoData.element_b);

    return var;
}
```

Then in QML, you can access is something like

```
var data_at_index = getData(index)
var a = data_at_index["elem_a"]
```

Your Repeater model can be just a Q_PROPERTY integer that returns the count of the list.